# Google Apps Script - get/assign user unique identifier

Tags: google-apps-script

I am developing a Google Docs Add-on and need to know if the user currently using the add-on has used it before in the current document or any document. I can't figure out which service gives me some kind of unique identifier for the current user that I can use to identify the current user.

The base service's User.getEmail is not good enough as it doesn't give access to the email under certain conditions and is not reliable.

Thoughts on best way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, there is no such service. Google wants users' personal information to remain private, so AFAIK you won't usually get even user's email, unless your script is written for Google Apps domain and the user is in the same domain as the script's author.

The only thing you can do in the situation is use something like [`DocumentApp.getActiveDocument().getId()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/document#getId()) and check if the script was used in this document, but of course this won't give you an idea if user has used your script in other documents or not.

Also you can show a [Prompt Dialog](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/dialogs#prompt_dialogs) to user, asking him to enter email, but of course there is no way you can check if he entered his real email.

Comment: Thanks Vyacheslav. I will try it out for myself but do you know if you can have Google sign-in within in add-on so that we can explicitly ask user to additionally identify themselves when they open up the add-on? I am basically trying to find a way for the add-on to know who the user is -but in a painless way.

Comment: @TheFatOracle you can, see updated answer. However, you can't rely on it too much, because you can't validate if this email address belongs to user.

Comment: thanks but I am looking for a solution that can be use to authenticate reliably and as you said, there is no way to check if a user entered his/her real email.
However, I think I've found a solution though I am still validating it. Please see my answer that I've added to this question and let me know if you think it might work.

Answer (score 0):

Unique user identifier you can get for apps script is Session.getEffectiveUser().getEmail()

This will return the email of user for which the script run. This is better than ActiveUser because if you use trigger EffectiveUser will well return the email of the user who install the script.

I use that for several apps to identify license assignment and it works great.

Comment: Thanks St3ph. Doesn't Session.getEffectiveUser().getEmail() return blank if the google apps domain security policies do not allow sharing of email - or indeed return blank if its a non Google Apps account (i.e. gmail account)?

Comment: I don't get your point about security policies. Whe user validate script access to his account EffectiveUser will always return his email. I use it a lot in all my script with no issue. For non google account they can access a script only if they run it as you so the owner will always be your email or if it is a public script so in this case user will not validate script access to his account and not sure but will always be blank.

Comment: St3ph, to explain my point - the reference documentation mentions that getActiveUser().getEmail() and getEffectiveUser().getEmail() may not work in the situation where the Google Apps admin has disallowed it via a security policy. This is important in my case as the add-on I am developing will be essentially be a 3rd party add-on that's not necessarily enabled domain wide. So there's a chance I will get a blank value instead of the user's email address. So this method may not prove reliable.

Comment: I checked the doc and see the point but the poicy is not explicitly mention. I have several client on Google apps and I never had this question. From my point of view I use a lot effective user with no issue. I think you can use it and track blank return to evaluate if it happens often. I'm pretty sure it will be marginal or never happens

Comment: Thanks for the opinion St3ph - I play in the Google Apps for Education world and schools tend to be stricter with policies - more so than 'normal' companies - so it's something I need to take into account. I have figured out another approach which might work better for me (see my 'answer') - and let me know if you have an opinion on that approach.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the best solution is to roll your own solution using the following to set the userId at an appropriate time:

```js
PropertiesService.getUserProperties().setProperty("userId",<someGeneratedUId>)
```

then whenever you want to look up if this user is a recognizable user,

```js
var userId = PropertiesServices.getUserProperties().getProperty("userId")
```

Looks like once set, the UserProperties thus set is available to this particular user (per user) running this add-on everywhere (i.e. all docs, not just the current on) that have this particular add-on enabled/running.

I'll validate this further but seems like this works in my tests.

Comment: Not sure but if the user uninstall the script the properties will be deleted. To be checked. Personally I use EffectiveUser and call library to validate if the user have an access validated. Except point about uninstall this can do the job.

Comment: Good point - I'll check about the case where the uninstall affects the properties.